# How to POST a batch of objects from a whole JSON file to REST API using Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON file that I need to POST to a REST API. The REST API has a limit of posting 2 records per batch. How can I do it? Sample JSON file provided below. If anybody can help me with this.

```
[{
        "name": "sa",
        "salary": 1000,
        "age": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "sb",
        "salary": 2000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sc",
        "salary": 3000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sd",
        "salary": 4000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "se",
        "salary": 5000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sf",
        "salary": 6000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sg",
        "salary": 7000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sh",
        "salary": 8000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "si",
        "salary": 9000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sj",
        "salary": 1000,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sk",
        "salary": 1100,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sl",
        "salary": 1200,
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "sm",
        "salary": 1300,
        "age": 20
    }
]
```

I am able to post the data from JSON file using lookup activity and to pass the output to Web Activity using `post` method, but I can't control the number of objects to be processed during the pipeline run.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above using **Set variables,lookup and until activities** and got below results.

First, I have taken a string set variable and given `'0'` value for iteration intialization.

[image]

Then after lookup used Until activity. Inside until activity I have taken 3 set variable activities. as ADF does not support self-referencing variables I have used a temporary string variable.

[image]

Next set variable creates an array of 2 objects with the following dynamic content using `iter` variable as index.

```
@createArray(activity('Lookup1').output.value[int(variables('iter'))],activity('Lookup1').output.value[add(int(variables('iter')),1)])
```

[image]

3rd set variable increments the `iter` by 2 with the following dynamic content.

```
@string(add(int(variables('temp')),2))
```

[image]

**Until activity**

```
@equals(div(int(variables('iter')),2),div(activity('Lookup1').output.count,2))
```

[image]

**Inside until activity you can use web activity and give that array variable to web activity body. **

The until stops for the last even numbered record.

You can see it iterated till 12th record.

[image]

**Then after until check the total data count (even or odd) using if activity**. If even pass the last two records by index using length of the lookup(like `length-1` and `length-2`) to web. If odd pass only last one record(`length-1`) to the web.**

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh..Let me try..I will update once done.